# setting http response header in mod pl/sql

Tags: plsql, mod-plsql

I have a mod pl/sql procedure with which I want to return a responce with a HTTP status code set to 404.  When sending a response via htp.p the HTTP status code is I believe by default set to 200.

How could this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call OWA_UTIL.status_line instead:

```
owa_util.status_line(nstatus=>404, creason=>'Not Found', bclose_header=>true);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/w_util.htm#ARPLS70790